# How to rewrite a sub domain to a url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to use a Rewrite rule in .htaccess to rewrite access from a sub domain (`michigan.sitename.com`) to a url - in this case, `http://sitename.org/content/michigan-21st-century-community-learning-centers`.

The site is based on Drupal.

This is what I have so far, the first few lines are from Drupal, everything after the linebreak is from me.

I am getting a 404 error trying the sub domain

```
  RewriteEngine on
  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

  # New information for Michigan sub domain
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^michigan.sitename\.com
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301, L]
```

Any advice would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Change your rule from:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^michigan.sitename\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301, L]
```

To:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^michigan\.sitename\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.sitename.com/content/michigan-21st-century-community-learning-centers [R=301,L]
```

You have a space after the `R=301,` which mod rewrite won't like, it's going to assume that there's another parameter and puke. Also you want to remove the `!` because you want to *match* the michigan subdomain. The URI is also going to be ignored, meaning if you go to:

```
http://michigan.sitename.com/
http://michigan.sitename.com/foo/bar
http://michigan.sitename.com/blah.html
```

will all get redirected to:

```
http://sitename.org/content/michigan-21st-century-community-learning-centers
```

You also want to swap the `Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.` rules with the `New information for Michigan sub domain` so that the michigan redirect happens first, otherwise the request will get routed through `index.php`. Or, you can add an additional condition to your index.php rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^michigan\.sitename\.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You must place the michigan rule first (for the rest, see jon lin's answer) :

```
  RewriteEngine on

  # New information for Michigan sub domain
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^michigan\.sitename\.com
  RewriteRule . http://www.sitename.com/content/michigan-21st-century-community-learning-centers [R=301,L]

  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```